# WordPress изменение размера фото

Tags: wordpress, изображения

При добавлении фото к записи с разрешением 1000px Х 500px, оно на странице отображается хорошо, но в миниатюрах оно режется и отображается ужасно.

Можно ли настроить так обрезку, чтобы она не резала изображение, а просто изменяло его по размеру?

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильно заданы размеры миниатюр в Настройки -> Медиафайлы. Измените их и проведите повторную регенерацию миниатюр с помощью плагина Regenerate Thumbnails.